# Mouse event function is not working

Tags: javascript

I have declared a function in JavaScript, and when calling `onClick` it does not work.

Here is my code:

```js
function delete(val) {
  alert(val);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<i class="fa fa-trash" onClick="delete('.$id.');">'.'</i>
```

Comment: Use a DevTools to check the JS error message. By the way, _delete_ is not the best name for the function.

Comment: You should be specific of what it deletes, should probably be function deleteCustomer(){} or something in that realm.

Comment: Without proper scoping, a top-level function called `delete` may confuse the browser with the actual `delete` reserved-word.

Comment: Voting to close because: _This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**._

Answer (score 0):

[delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) is a reserved word in JavaScript. Use a different name for your function.

```js
function del(val) {
  alert(val);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<i class="fa fa-trash" onClick="del('.$id.');">'.'</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete is a reserved word in javascript used to delete a property from an object.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

> The delete operator removes a property from an object.

So you can't use it as a function name.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<i class="fa fa-trash" onClick="del('.$id.');">.</i>

<script type="text/javascript">
function del(val){

alert(val);

}

</script>
```